Soldering iron melts solder on direct contact but not when trying to solder two wires
This is my first "big boy" attempt at soldering.
I'm trying to solder two relatively thin DC wires. Everything I got is cheap from AliExpress. Soldering iron is a 80W simple piece that came with some solder and wires in a set for ~$20.
I seem to be able to easily melt solder directly on the soldering iron tip. I understand the proper way to solder the two wires is by heating the wires with the tip and then letting the hot wires melt the solder, and this is the part I'm struggling with. The wires do feel hot, but the solder doesn't melt.
I make sure I:

I use a tip that isn't corroded.
Iron temperature is set at 350C and I let it warm up before using it.
I let some solder melt on the tip for better connection with the wires.
I wait a lot longer than what I've seen on youtube for the wires to heat up enough.

What am I missing?
Anything else to check in order to understand the problem?

Get a buddy to take a photo of the tip, two wires and solder all in contact. Crop it nicely and upload it into your question.

@Transistor Thanks. Will do!

What kind of wire are you using?

Is the wire copper and what is its gauge?  Try adding some rosin flux to the wires before soldering.

is there a chance that they are coil wires? these are coated and can't be soldered without preparation

Make sure it is not enamelled copper wire because that's impossible to solder on. If you away scratch the surface with a knife and then you can suddenly solder just fine, then that is the case.

There’s some confusion I think related to what it means to apply solder to hot wires. It’s pretty simple: the wires will not heat up well if the tip has no solder on it.

Apply a small blob of solder to the tip just to aid thermal contact from soldering iron to the wire. This is for thermal reasons only, and not the solder that does the soldering job.

Now that the tip can do a good job of heating up the wires, the wires will get hot enough to melt solder.

If the wires are too thin and pose too high thermal resistance between the tip contact point and the soldering point, this won’t work.


Personally, I stick the well-tinned blobby tip on the contact point of the two wires. Then as soon as the wires get hot, I apply solder right where the tip and the wires meet. It takes some dexterity to maneuver the two wire ends and the soldering iron and the solder wire with just two hands. Ideally the wires should be held in a work holder in correct relative position and touching. Then the hands are free to position the solder wire and the soldering iron.

If solder easily sticks to the hot tip, then it should easily stick to the tip of each wire.
If not, is it aluminum wire? Is it coated wire? Is it corroded wire?
If none of the above. Retry transferring a bit of solder with just enough to coat each wire tip adding a tiny bit of solder and heat at the same time.
Then bonding them together should take less than half a second with thin wires tightly twisted ( >=2 turns) in line. The twists provide mechanical strength amplified by the solder. Wire bonds should withstand a 5 lb or 2 kg pull test, if the wire is strong enough.
Use heat shrink tubing a few inches away from heat for a pro job without sharp edges..

Make sure there is no oxidation or other coating on the wire.  In particular, magnet wire is sometimes clear or orange and looks just like wire.  Just scrape the wire and see if it gets shinier, and then try to solder to that.  All your best intentions (and mine) are useless if the wire won't take solder in the first place.

I just happen to have this sprinkler valve in front of me. You'll notice the wire looks bare but that would not work if wound in a coil. It would be one big short circuit.  So we can conclude that it must be insulated in some manner.


Make sure your wires are clean and not oxidized, using flux if necessary. Solder flows towards hot metal, but it "runs away" from contaminants.

Solder is a good conductor of heat and increases the effective contact area between the iron and the work. It's okay to have a blob of solder on the tip when you bring it to the joint. If it's too much then you risk having it fall off and land where it shouldn't, or flooding the joint with too much solder when it wicks off of the tip and onto the work. But having the right amount is good and helpful.


